# Pytube takes too long to respond

Tags: python, pytube

im trying to make a youtube downloader using pytube. First i tested getting just the title from the video by user input

```
from pytube import YouTube

link = input("type a youtube url: ")
#path = input("where you want to download")

yt = YouTube(link)

print(yt.title)
```

it works but it takes about 2 minutes just to get the title, it will take forever to do anything else. What is the problem? There is a way to make it faster?

Comment: I just did a quick test. Takes 0 seconds to retrieve title for me. Try a different network?

Comment: There appears to be nothing wrong with your code - check your internet connection, VPN, other software using the network, etc.

Comment: @Grismar i reseted my pc and it works for now, my internet is kinda bad but i thought 7mb download was enought just for the title